# CLIPS: convert boolean to integer

Tags: type-conversion, clips

I need to convert a boolean (result of logic expression) into an integer (0 | 1).
I haven't seen inside the guide a specific command.
Do I need to write a function or is there a quickest way?

Thank you in advance,
Nicola

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a function:

```
CLIPS> 
(deffunction BooleanToInteger (?bool)
   (if ?bool then 1 else 0))
CLIPS> (BooleanToInteger FALSE)
0
CLIPS> (BooleanToInteger TRUE)
1
CLIPS>
```